# Using QMDIArea with Qt 4.4.

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qmdiarea

I'm using the `QMdiArea` in Qt 4.4.

If a new project is created, I add a number of sub windows to a `QMdiArea`. I'd like to disallow the user to close a sub window during runtime. The sub windows should only be closed if the whole application is closed or if a new project is created.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you sub-class QMdiArea and override the default closeActiveSubWindow/closeAllSubWindows methods to not close the window when user requests it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your own `subWindow`. create a subclass of `QMdiSubWindow` and override the `closeEvent(QCloseEvent *closeEvent)`. you can control it by argument. for example:

```
void ChildWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *closeEvent)
{
  if(/*condition C*/)
    closeEvent->accept();
  else
   closeEvent->ignore(); // you can do something else, like 
                         // writing a string in status bar ...
}
```

then subclass the `QMdiArea` and override `QMdiArea::closeAllSubWindows ()` like this:

```
class MainWindowArea : public QMdiArea
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindowArea(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void closeAllSubWindows();
public slots:

};
// Implementation:
MainWindowArea::closeAllSubWindows()
{
    // set close condition (new project is creating, C = true)
    foreach(QMdiSubWindow* sub,this->subWindowList())
    {
        (qobject_cast<ChildWindow*>(sub))->close();
    }
}
```

you may also need to override `close` slot of your mdi area.

Comment: Yes, that is a posibility. It does not remove the "x" in the top right corner but it works right. Actually i was looking for a solution which although removes this "x", too.

Comment: Probably you can overcome by re-implementing the paint event of mdiArea... but it's hard stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do this the same as for a top-level window: process and ignore the QCloseEvent it sent. QMdiArea::closeActiveSubWindow/QMdiArea::closeAllSubWindows just call QWidget::close, which sends a closeEvent and confirms that it was accepted before proceeding.

You can process this event by subclassing QMdiSubWindow and reimplementing QWidget::closeEvent, or by using an event filter to intercept it..